# ffmpeg - switch rtmp streams into a single encoded output?

Tags: ffmpeg, rtmp, http-live-streaming

I have `1-5` input streams, each uploading on a slightly different time offset.

With rtmp and ffmpeg, I can reliably encode a single stream into an HLS playlist that plays seamlessly on iOS, my target delivery platform.

I know that you can accept multiple input streams into ffmpeg, and I want to switch between the input streams to create a consistent, single, seamless output.

So I want to switch between 
`rtmp://localhost/live/stream1` .. `rtmp://localhost/live/stream5` on a regular interval. Sometimes there will be multiple streams, and sometimes there won't.

Is there any way for ffmpeg to rotate between input streams while generating an HLS playlist? My goal is to avoid running duplicate instances of ffmpeg for server cost reasons, and I think connecting disparately encoded input streams for playback would be difficult if not impossible.

Switching on each segment is the ideal behavior, but I also need to keep the streams in time sync. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Switching live stream inputs can cause delays due to the initial connection time and buffering (`rtmp_buffer`).

There's no straight-forward way to do it with `ffmpeg`. Being an open source project you can add the functionality yourself. It shouldn't be very complicated if all all your inputs share the same codecs, number of tracks, frame sizes etc.

[Some people suggested](https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2014-August/022825.html) using another software to do the switch such as MLT or using filters such as `zmq` (ZeroMQ) to make `ffmpeg` accept commands.

One way to do it would be to re-stream the source as `mpgets` on a local port and use the local address as input in the command that outputs the `HLS`:

Stream switcher (60s of each stream, one at a time) - you can make a script with your own logic, this is for illustrative purposes:

```
ffmpeg -re -i rtmp://.../stream1 -t 60 -f mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:10000
ffmpeg -re -i rtmp://.../stream2 -t 60 -f mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:10000
[...]
ffmpeg -re -i rtmp://.../stream5 -t 60 -f mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:10000
```

Use the local address as source for the `HLS` stream - it'll wait for input if there's none and fix your DTS/PTS but you will probably introduce some delays on switching:

```
ffmpeg -re -i udp://127.0.0.1:10000 /path/to/playlist.m3u8
```